# FPDI: internal link using TCPDF addLink()

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to create an internal link in my PDF using TCPDF

I create the link at the start of my document:

```
    $pdf = new ManualPDF ();

    $link = $pdf->addLink();
    $pdf->SetLink($link);
```

and then create a link to it later:

```
    $pdf->Write(0,'Click Here',$link);
```

however this doesn't work, and the Click Here text doesn't even appear clickable on the PDF (cursor is Caret).

Any guidance?

**EDIT**

ManualPDF is an extension of FPDI, sorry I should have mentioned that originally

Comment: what do you mean by internal link

Comment: waht is ManualPDF? have ypu extended the default TCPDF. I check your code it is working perfectly at my end

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a6669ae88090963e9487d0388c7577dc9), you can use the `Write()` method on your TCPDF object to achieve this.

For example:

```
//Line height 
$lh = 10;

//Indicates if the cell background must be painted (true) or transparent (false). 
$bg = false;

//L or empty string: left align (default value)
$align = 'L';

//If true set cursor at the bottom of the line, otherwise set cursor at the top of the line. 
$ln = true;

$link = 'http://www.example.com/';
$tcpdf->Write($lh, 'Example Link', $link, $bg, $align, $ln);
```

Would write a line with the text Google (left-aligned and with a line break, just added for a better example).

This could help you better!